# React not resetting form values when user opens a new form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I have some interesting behaviour that I'm trying to understand in my React Application below. I'm finding form values aren't resetting when a user starts a new form submission and I'm trying to understand why.

We have a Dashboard component, which had a button allowing users to create a new project.

The button is below:

```
     <HrefLink
         to={"/project/new"}
         state={{ projects: rows }}
     >
         <Button id="newProject" variant="contained" size="Small">
             New
         </Button>
    </HrefLink>
```

Fairly simple stuff. Under the NewProject route, we import defaultValues for new projects via a constants file:

```
    import { defaultValues } from "../constants/consts";

    export default function NewProject() {
        const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(defaultValues);
        ...
        ...
    }
```

consts.jsx:

```
    export const defaultValues = {
        name: "",
        description: "",
        startDate: new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)),
        endDate: "",
        status: "DRAFT"
    }
```

Again, fairly simple. However, I'm finding what's happening is I can start a new form, go through the steps, enter values, etc (I am running on localhost). Then, without submitting the form - I just click back home instead, I can come back to my application the next day, and I find when I start a new form again, the startDate is being set as the previous day instead of today's date. I.E: a new form is not being set with the default values.

Just this morning I can see:
formValues.startDate:
Tue Nov 21 2023 00:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)

Todays actual date if using new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) should be:
Wed Nov 22 2023 00:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)

Looks like the state isn't being reset if a user doesn't submit the form, so I'm wondering how I can force this reset to occur. Any suggestions?

Comment: alll form fields are stored only within useState?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: then use the return cleanup function from useEffect to clear state. that will run when your component unmounts i.e. when you go to your home component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the clean up function from useEffect which will run uncomponent unmounts so in you case that could clear the form state

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Anything in here is fired on component mount.
  return () => {
    // Anything in here is fired on component unmount.

  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was also able to make the following update to reset the state:

consts.jsx:

    export const defaultValues = () =>{
      return{
        name: "",
        description: "",
        startDate: new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)),
        endDate: "",
        status: "DRAFT"
      }
    }

and then:
[formValues, setFormValues] = useState(defaultValues()),

Answer (score 0):

After taking into account object referential equality, I was also able to make the below updates to reset the state:

consts.jsx:

```
    export const defaultValues = () =>{
      return{
        name: "",
        description: "",
        startDate: new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)),
        endDate: "",
        status: "DRAFT"
      }
    }
```

and then:

```
[formValues, setFormValues] = useState(defaultValues())
```